# SVN move the contents of a directory into its parent

Tags: svn

I'm having trouble figuring out the svn commands needed to move the contents of a directory up one level into its parent and then deleting that directory. In unix I would do:

```
$ cd ~/parentdir/subdir
$ mv * ..
$ cd ..
$ rm -r subdir
```

Now all the files that were under subdir are now in parentdir and subdir is now gone. How would I do the same in SVN while maintaining the history of those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cd ~/parentdir/subdir
$ svn cp * ..
$ cd ..
$ svn rm subdir
$ svn ci -m"Copy parentdir/subdir/* into parentdir, remove subdir"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's easier than I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

[this is really a comment, but i'm lacking the reputation for it]

use `$ svn cp * .[^.]* ..` instead if you want to copy dotfiles and .folders/, too.

found at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory), which shows alternate ways to do the same.